# How to get the name of the instance of the parent class from the derived class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, instance

Hi i want to get the instance name of base class from the inherited child class.

for ex.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, fakeArg):
        self.a = fakeArg

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, fakeArg1):
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.b = fakeArg1
        # say, i store parent(Foo) instance in an variable too
        self.c = f

f = Foo('Hello')
b = Bar('Bar')
```

Now i want to attach(relate) "f" to "b", such that if i instantiate class Bar as b, it should also store which instance of parent class is calling the derived class instance.

one way to do it is to parse parent class(Foo) instance "f" as an argument to the "**_*init*_**" method of class(Bar).But, that is kind of a hack.

Kindly provide a solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. When you instantiate `Bar`, no `Foo` instance is being made (apart from the `Bar` instance, which is a `Foo` instance by virtue of inheritance). Passing `f` as a parameter is not a hack, it's the proper solution to certain problems. Whether it's the solution to your problem depends on the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: I'm confused. First, I don't understand the question.  Second,  This code won't work -- You're not passing enough arguments to `Foo.__init__` from `Bar.__init__`.

Comment: Also, you should use `super` to do any init stuff in the parent.

Comment: @larsmans ... thanks for clearing the "hack" part.

Comment: @ wim  ..... i changed __init__ of parent class to super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be confused about how inheritance works in Python. In the code you showed, `f` and `b` are not related, except by being instantiated right next to each other.

However, your `Bar` instance `b` does have access to a `Foo` instance, namely itself. By declaring that `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo` you are saying that every instance of `Bar` is also an instance of `Foo`. You can test this, with `isinstance(b, Foo)`.

If you need to access a variable or method defined in `Foo` from a method of `bar`, usually you can just access it directly on the `self` value you get passed. Or if you're overriding a method in `Bar` (that is, defining a method with the same name as one that already exists in `Foo` you can use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#super):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def sayHello(self):
        print("Hello!")

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(self, a)  # calls overridden __init__ method from Foo
        self.b = b

    def doSomething(self):
        self.sayHello()            # calls a method defined in Foo
        return self.a + self.b     # accesses variable "a" that was set in Foo
```

(Note that the code above is for Python 3. There are a few small things that will make it not work correctly in Python 2. If your learning Python for any reason other than maintaining a legacy Python 2 application, I suggest learning with Python 3.)

Comment: Blckknght ... thanks for the reply, i am new to the language.

Answer (score 2):

What sounds like a hack for you is how you should do it.

Remember that there might be tons of instances of each class so it **cannot** automatically know which one is supposed to be "related" to it - and using any kinds of magic (such as checking the parent stack frame for a variable holding an instance of `Foo` and hoping that's the only one) would be extremely ugly and a reason to slap you hard in the face if I were your boss.

So, you **should** pass `f` as an argument to `Bar()`.

In case you do not want a separate `Foo` instance - i.e. you want normal inheritance - there's no need to create an instance of `Foo`, simply call `Foo.__init__(self, 'Hello')` or `super(Bar, self).__init__('Hello')` in the `Bar` constructor and possibly accept the value as an argument instead of hardcoding it.